# TypeError: Cannot read property 'firebase' of undefined in NativeScript app

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, nativescript

I'm creating a mobile app by using NativeScript with AngularJS2 & TypeScript. For using Firebase as DB to store data.

For using firebase in NativeScript I'm suing the following library - https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase

Here is my code -

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {User} from "./shared/user/user";
import {UserService} from "./shared/user/user.service";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/http";
var firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  providers: [UserService, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  templateUrl: "pages/login/login.html",
  styleUrls: ["pages/login/login-common.css", "pages/login/login.css"]
})

export class AppComponent {
    user: User;
    isLoggingIn = true;

    constructor(private _userService: UserService) {
        this.user = new User();
    }

    submit() {
        if (this.isLoggingIn) {
            this.login();
        } else {
            this.signUp();
        }
    }

    login() {
        // TODO: Define
        console.log('Clicked on Login button');

        firebase.init({
            persist: true // Allow disk persistence. Default false.
        }).then(
            function (instance) {
                console.log("firebase.init done");
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
            }
        );
    }

    signUp() {
        this._userService.register(this.user);
    }

    toggleDisplay() {
        this.isLoggingIn = !this.isLoggingIn;
    }
}
```

Method "Login()" is getting invoked when a user clicks on "Sign in" button.  I've pasted that firebase code for checking everything is fine with firebase or not.

But, whenever that "Login()" is invoked it's showing following error.

```
JS: Clicked on Login button
JS: Error in firebase.init: TypeError: Cannot read property 'firebase' of undefined
JS: firebase.init error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'firebase' of undefined
```

I can understand this error is showing because I'm not properly inserting that "firebase" dependency inside the class. But, as I'm new to TypeScript I can't able to understand.. how to do it.

Need some help

Edited -

Getting following error from VS Code when using `import * as firebase from "nativescript-plugin-firebase";` rather than `var firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");`

[image]

Comment: Have you run `tns plugin add nativescript-plugin-firebase` ?

Comment: If you change your `var firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");` to `import * as firebase from "nativescript-plugin-firebase"` then you should get some IntelliSense which may help you debug.

Comment: Yeah, I've added the plugin to my app by this command ```tns plugin add nativescript-plugin-firebase```

Comment: and did you follow the full setup [instructions](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase#installation), including the platform files? Are you using VSCode, or an IDE with IntelliSense? If so, change the import statement, and let me know if 1. there are any compiler warnings thrown by your code and 2. if you type `firebase.` do any auto-complete suggestions come up? This should show us whether your plugin is accessible from this code.

Comment: Yes, I'm using VS Code editor & also followed all the instructions given in plugin docs. Ok.. If I use following line ```import * as firebase from "nativescript-plugin-firebase";``` then, I'm IntelliSense error coming as - ```Can't find module nativescript-plugin-firebase```

Comment: Try adding `/// <reference path="node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts" /> ` at the top

Comment: I added that ```/// <reference path="node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.d.ts" />``` but it also showing file not found error whereas ```firebase.d.ts``` file is there in the folder.

Comment: I think you need to do a relative path, so add ../ as many times as you need to get the correct reference

Comment: Ok, one doubt. Is that path should be like this - ```../node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.android.js``` ?

Comment: Yes, that could be correct, it depends how you have structured your app, (one `../` for each file level you need to move up before you can access the node_modules file branch)

Comment: Right now there seems to be a problem with the latest version of the plugin.. try installing a previous release with tns plugin add nativescript-plugin-firebase@2.1.8

Comment: @NickIliev : Just wanted to ask, the code which I've posted.. is that the right way to do or I should in some other way ?

Comment: did you finally solve this? i have the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

`import firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");`
in reference.d.ts add `/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase" />` (without extensions)

Comment: When I'm doing that one in file ```reference.d.ts``` I'm getting error for "file not found" with full path

Comment: Should be problem in file location though. Its compulsory to reference that file in `reference.d.ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

you should enable multiDex in your app.gradle and remove and rebuild the app

```
android {
 defaultConfig {
 applicationId "com.mysite.myproj"
 generatedDensities = []
 multiDexEnabled true
}
```

See [This issue](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/41) form more details